# How to download Maven repostory?

Tags: java, maven

I have a closed private network (no connection to internets - actually, no connection to any other network).

I want to copy some of external repositories (not Maven Central) to this network.

It shouldn't be a caching mirror, but a full snapshot.
I will do this procedure every morning - download everything, and then manually move all this artifacts to the private network.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you want the _whole_ repository? There are mechanisms for "going offline" which grab all the artifacts you need for your builds.

Answer (score 0):

You will want something like Sonatype Nexus (https://www.sonatype.com/products-sonatype). You should be able to then use it to deploy some of your maven dependencies and artifacts. You can then upload maven artefacts here and then use this repository for applications to connect and then get the dependencies you need.

[image]

Comment: We already have Nexus in the "private network". I want to transfer artifacts to this network and this Nexus.

The things is, external repositories contain thousands of artifacts, manual downloading and uploading will take forever.

How can I automate downloading whole repositories?

Comment: With your answer, I download all my external repositories to a USB flash drive, move this artifacts to the private network, and upload artifacts to Nexus. I can automate uploading with Nexus REST API, but still don't know how to automate downloading